# Query on trip plan tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables and attributes in brackets:

- route (route_id, route_name)
- routestop (route_id, stop_id)
- stops (stop_id, stop_name)

route_id and stop_id in routestop are foreign keys referencing the primary keys in route and stops respectively. Now given a stop_name can fall in multiple routes and say I query from a form containing a from stop_name field and a to stop_name field, how can I obtain results showing route names and stop names based on the input parameters I query.

Thanks

I will try and rephrase it. I am working on a trip planner application in which i want a commuter to input two parameters in a form containing a FROM(origin stop_name) and a TO(destination stop_name) e.g. from(New York city) to(Buffalo). Based on the table info in my question i want the commuter to obtain results assuming there could be more than one routes to get to his/her destination. I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand this at all.

Comment: What is the question? Don't you think is better to accomplish with some query snippet for better understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this type of query that you're looking for is called "set-within-sets".

One way way to approach it is to use `GROUP BY` aggregation (by route in your case) and check for conditions (ensure that both stops are in route) in `HAVING` clause.

Assuming that you get `stop_id`s in your client code (e.g. origin stop_id is 1 and destination stop_id is 3) and if you're interested only in routes info your query may look like

```sql
SELECT r.*
  FROM route_stop rs JOIN routes r
    ON rs.route_id = r.route_id
 WHERE rs.stop_id IN(1,3)
 GROUP BY rs.route_id
HAVING MAX(rs.stop_id = 1) + 
       MAX(rs.stop_id = 3) = 2 -- both stop_ids should be present for each route
```

Sample output:

```
| ROUTE_ID | ROUTE_NAME |
|----------|------------|
|        1 |     route1 |
|        2 |     route2 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b1ab/2)** demo

If you want to see routes and all the stops

```sql
SELECT r.*, GROUP_CONCAT(s.stop_name) stops
  FROM
(
  SELECT route_id
    FROM route_stop
   WHERE stop_id IN(1,3)
   GROUP BY route_id
  HAVING MAX(stop_id = 1) + 
         MAX(stop_id = 3) = 2
) q JOIN route_stop rs 
    ON q.route_id = rs.route_id JOIN routes r
    ON rs.route_id = r.route_id JOIN stops s
    ON rs.stop_id = s.stop_id
 GROUP BY rs.route_id
```

Sample output:

```
| ROUTE_ID | ROUTE_NAME |             STOPS |
|----------|------------|-------------------|
|        1 |     route1 | stop5,stop3,stop1 |
|        2 |     route2 | stop1,stop3,stop2 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b1ab/4)** demo

Comment: It worked like a charm! thanks amillion peterm. Would you be kind enough to refer me to a good mysql book, tutorial or a site to enhance my skill in this particular area?

Comment: You're quite welcome. E.g. [SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) by Bill Karwin and [SQL Performance Explained](http://sql-performance-explained.com) by Markus Winand

Comment: would you care to please explain the query? I'm confused by the MAX stop ids. Like why are you using 1 and 3 ?